# ReactiveUi how to use ICollectionView with the Getting started example

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm learning ReactiveUi and trying the sample from here https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/ This is a great examle, but now I would like to replace the List SearchResults with a ICollectionView to have more grouping / sorting capability.

The documentation contains a ReactiveCollectionViewSource [here](https://reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/reactivecollectionviewsource_1/61104db4) and but I'm unable to find a sample how to use it with the starting code. Is that the right track?

Comment: Consider using dynamic data by Roland pheasant. It handles grouping filtering in a reactive way. Most people on the project use it in their personal projects. https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData

Comment: Thanks will have a try

Comment: Just wondering, what about ReactiveCollectionViewSource ?

Comment: you should be able to use it like any other binding, either RxUI binding or WPF binding. You would use the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list) to generate the view.

Comment: The ReactiveCollectionViewSource btw is for iOS users. Also be aware that the ReactiveList is going to be deprecated and put into legacy mode soon in favour of DynamicData.

Comment: Also worth noting I added a issue due to your confusion, I don't want to have another user confused due to platform specific code https://github.com/reactiveui/website/issues/130

Comment: DynamicData, it rocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReactiveCollectionViewSource is for the iOS project only.

You should be able to use standard WPF ways of generating your CollectionView and use CollectionViewSource.GetDefault() etc.

You can then use WPF or ReactiveUI bindings to bind that to your controls.

One thing of note is that DynamicData is going to be in the near future the preferred solution for data management in RxUI projects. Worth seeing if it fits in your problem space. https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData - There is a DynamicData channel on the Reactive slack channel if you need help with the framework https://reactiveui.net/slack

Comment: Thanks, having the plateform info would be great.